# What is the best way to plot time duration over time?

Tags: r, gnuplot, visualization

What's the best way to plot time based data?

don't want to limit by implementation yet, but would be nice if it is possible in gnuplot or r alone.

The data have start time of network requests, and the time it took to complete. Normally those graphs are displayed with Y axis being duration, and X axis being time. But since a tall Y axis can "bleed" into processing time for a future request, it would be nice to see that on the plot somehow.

the data i have contain the start time and then fields for specific types of delay for the request, which can be ignored and just summed up to mean "duration" (normally they are just shown as stacked bar graphs on the Y axis)

e.g. data, which I get from apachebench (`ab`)

```
starttime                   seconds     ctime   dtime   ttime   wait
Mon Oct 17 10:53:49 2022    1666029229  0   158 158 158
Mon Oct 17 10:53:50 2022    1666029230  0   158 158 158
Mon Oct 17 10:53:49 2022    1666029229  0   158 200 158
Mon Oct 17 10:53:50 2022    1666029230  0   158 257 158
Mon Oct 17 10:53:49 2022    1666029229  0   158 300 158
Mon Oct 17 10:53:49 2022    1666029229  0   158 154 158
```

i'm currently trying to came up with an accumulator using https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/linkedaxes.html but i'm far from sure that will be a good solution.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you actually want to plot. What I understand: you have timestamp (where a request starts) and its duration. Since you seem to have several requests starting at the same time (possibly with different duration), I assume you want to nevertheless display them (probably shifted in y-direction and maybe different color). Correct? Maybe something like a kind of Gantt-Chart but with horizontal boxes? https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/gantt.html

Comment: correct. Gantt would be ideal, except plots would have dozen to hundreds of thousands of requests. With an average of hundreds being kept alive at the same time.

Comment: Typically hundreds at the same time and you all want to see them? Can you be a bit more precise and give a number N (or a range)? So, then your graph should have at least a height of N (or multiple of N) pixels. Ok, and approx. 10'000 to 100'000 requests in total. And what is the typical (min./max.) duration? What I see from the limited data is 470 to 616. What is the unit? Milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: milliseconds. requests take from 200ms to 6s.

Comment: is there such a thing as a gantt heat map?

Comment: what is the approx. time range of your data? Minutes, hours, days, weeks?

Comment: most of the samples are under 1min. at most <=4minutes

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? If yes, please check the check mark to accept the answer and to indicate that the question is answered, if not please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The following is maybe a starting point in order to get closer what you are looking for.
Since I don't have your data, the script creates some random test data.
1000 random start times within 4 minutes after starttime `t0` and three random durations (within 0-2 seconds) are created in a table.

Now, you can plot these durations at the starttime on x with the plotting style `with vectors` (check `help vectors`). Here, the y-coordinate is the row index. With this you avoid overlaps between parallel processes.
However, I assume you now want to get rid of all the empty space between the lines. If this is what you are looking for, I can think about how to do this with gnuplot.

**Script:** (edit: duration of request colored via palette)

```
### plot duration of processes vs. time
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    t0 = 1666029229
    dt = 60*4
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (t=t0+int(rand(0)*dt),strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",t)):\
        (sprintf("%.0f",t)):(0):(rand(0)*2):(rand(0)*2):(rand(0)*2) w table
unset table

set key noautotitle
set format x "%M:%S" timedate
set tics out
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10

plot $Data u 6:0:(dt=$8+$9+$10):(0):(dt) w vec nohead lc palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

In the above script, the random data was unsorted and the row index was simply taken as y-value, hence, there was no "risk" of overlapping bars at any time. However, this creates a lot of empty space which you probably want to minimize, i.e. compress the whole view.

In order to plot the "compressed" bars *without* overlap you better sort the data by starting time. Well, gnuplot is not good at sorting (internally), but since gnuplot 5.4.0 at least you have the option `smooth zsort` (check `help zsort`).

In advance you don't know how many requests (at maximum) are running in parallel. Well, minimum 0 and (in your case) maximum 100'000, but as you said, typically around 100. In the example below with 1'000 random requests, typically around 25 requests are running in parallel.

What the script does:

- initialize an array `X` for memorizing the end time of the latest request at position y. You have to guess the size of that array (here: N=100 or take the max. 1'000).
- define a function `findY()` which is (mis)using `sum` to find the lowest y where `X[y]` is smaller than the current time `x0` (check `help sum`).

In the example below at around 56:20 the maximum of 24 requests were running in parallel.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### plot duration of processes vs. time (compressed)
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    t0 = 1666029229
    dt = 60*4
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (t=t0+int(rand(0)*dt),strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",t)):\
        (sprintf("%.0f",t)):(0):(rand(0)*2):(rand(0)*2):(rand(0)*2) w table
unset table

set table $Temp
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot $Data u 6:($8+$9+$10):6 smooth zsort
unset table

N = 100
array X[N]
findY(x0,dx)  = (i0=NaN, sum[_i=1:N] ( X[_i]<x0 && i0!=i0 ? (X[_i]=x0+dx, i0=_i) : 0), i0)

set key noautotitle
set format x "%M:%S" timedate
set tics out
set offsets 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set style fill solid 1.0 border lc "black"
set ylabel "Number of requests running in parallel" font ",11"
set cblabel "duration / s"
set grid y

plot c=0 $Temp u (c==0? (c=1, sum[_i=1:N] X[_i]=0) :0, $1+$2/2.):(findY($1,$2)):($2/2.):(0.5):2 w boxxy lc palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]